# Magento2 How can i show search field through wysiwyg editor?

Tags: magento2

Magento2 how can i show search field though wysywyg editor?
I am using theme inherted by default blank theme.

Comment: Did you mean you want to call catalog Search From Static Block or CMS pages ?

Comment: Yes you are right. i want to call it from static block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to call Search Form in Cms Page Use the below Code in your Cms Page you will get Search Box you can call any of the cms Pages :

*{{block class="Magento\Search\Block\Term" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"}}*

After Save the CMS Page Run The below Command

**php bin/magento cache:flush & php bin/magento cache:clean this will work**